# Jquery Parse Excel XML to Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, xml, excel, 2d

Ok. My code is apparently missing something. I am trying to parse and XML document into an array of arrays (2D array). The parent array should be the rows, and the subarrays should be the data in . One problem is that I am using an XML document generated by Excel. I saved it in Excel so I could retain formatting, and so other people can edit the XML easily. The Excel XML output looks like this:

```
<Row ss:Index="9" ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">George</Data></Cell>
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Carlson</Data></Cell>
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">65</Data></Cell>
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
</Row>
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Anna</Data></Cell>
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Dooley</Data></Cell>
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">33</Data></Cell>
 <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">A</Data></Cell>
</Row>
```

As I was saying previously, I want the parent array to contain the 'Row's, and I want the subarrays to contain the text in the 'Data's. My debugging program keeps telling me the array I am creating with my code is undefined:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var Array, typeA, typeB, typeC, typeD;

$.ajax({
          url: 'file.xml',
          type: 'GET', 
          dataType: 'xml',
          success: function(returnedXMLResponse){

            $('Row', returnedXMLResponse).each(function(){
            Array = $('Data', this).text();
        })
    }           
 });
```

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is overwriting the variable `Array` on every iteration of the `each` loop.

What you want is to define an outer array and on each row iteration create either a new array ( or object) and push that into the outer array

```js
var Array = [];

$.ajax({
    url: 'file.xml',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (returnedXMLResponse) {
        $(returnedXMLResponse).find('Row').each(function () {
            var rowArray = []; // sub array
            /* loop over each cell */
            $('Data', this).each(function () {
                rowArray.push($(this).text());
            });
            /* push row into main array */
            Array.push(rowArray);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. :( Any idea why it wouldn't work? Also, in case this matters, I am using jquery-1.11.1.js. It still says Array is undefined when I debug.

Comment: Should I maybe do $('Cell'.'Data', this).each(function () {

Comment: Oh yeah, and I am using IE10. It is a work environment so I cannot upgrade.

Comment: Tried newest version of jquery and had same issue. Script runs fine with no errors, but Array just ends up undefined.

Comment: My guess is you are trying to access `Array` outside of the success callback before data is returned. ajax is asynchronous